# JCR SQL2 fulltext search in node properties and all child nodes

Tags: sql, jcr

I'm trying to do a fulltext search in JCR SQL2. The query should return all nodes which have at least one property containing the search string or they have child nodes with properties containing the same string. Here's what I have so far:

```
select * from [nt:base] as t where ocm_classname = 'info.magnolia.cv.CurriculumVitae' and contains(t.*, 'java')
```

This solves the first part, selects all nodes with the specified `ocm_classname` and at least one property containing the word 'java'. But I can't figure out how to search for nodes which don't have properties containing the word 'java' but have child nodes with properties containing the word. For example this node should be found:

```
<sv:node sv:name="cv1362044004066">
    <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
        <sv:value>nt:unstructured</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="address" sv:type="String">
        <sv:value>Chicago, IL</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="currentDepartment" sv:type="String">
        <sv:value>dotNet</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="currentRole" sv:type="String">
        <sv:value>Project Manager</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="dateOfBirth" sv:type="Date">
        <sv:value>1981-01-14T00:05:00.000-05:00</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="id" sv:type="String">
        <sv:value>1362044004066</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="name" sv:type="String">
        <sv:value>John Carpenter</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="ocm_classname" sv:type="String">
        <sv:value>info.magnolia.cv.CurriculumVitae</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:node sv:name="skills">
        <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
            <sv:value>nt:unstructured</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
        <sv:node sv:name="collection-element">
            <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
                <sv:value>nt:unstructured</sv:value>
            </sv:property>
            <sv:property sv:name="level" sv:type="String">
                <sv:value>Advanced</sv:value>
            </sv:property>
            <sv:property sv:name="name" sv:type="String">
                <sv:value>Management</sv:value>
            </sv:property>
            <sv:property sv:name="ocm_classname" sv:type="String">
                <sv:value>info.magnolia.cv.CVSkills</sv:value>
            </sv:property>
        </sv:node>
        <sv:node sv:name="collection-element">
            <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
                <sv:value>nt:unstructured</sv:value>
            </sv:property>
            <sv:property sv:name="level" sv:type="String">
                <sv:value>Advanced</sv:value>
            </sv:property>
            <sv:property sv:name="name" sv:type="String">
                <sv:value>Scrum</sv:value>
            </sv:property>
            <sv:property sv:name="ocm_classname" sv:type="String">
                <sv:value>info.magnolia.cv.CVSkills</sv:value>
            </sv:property>
        </sv:node>
        <sv:node sv:name="collection-element">
            <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
                <sv:value>nt:unstructured</sv:value>
            </sv:property>
            <sv:property sv:name="level" sv:type="String">
                <sv:value>Advanced</sv:value>
            </sv:property>
            <sv:property sv:name="name" sv:type="String">
                <sv:value>Java</sv:value>
            </sv:property>
            <sv:property sv:name="ocm_classname" sv:type="String">
                <sv:value>info.magnolia.cv.CVSkills</sv:value>
            </sv:property>
        </sv:node>
        <sv:node sv:name="collection-element">
            <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
                <sv:value>nt:unstructured</sv:value>
            </sv:property>
            <sv:property sv:name="level" sv:type="String">
                <sv:value>Intermediate</sv:value>
            </sv:property>
            <sv:property sv:name="name" sv:type="String">
                <sv:value>Spring</sv:value>
            </sv:property>
            <sv:property sv:name="ocm_classname" sv:type="String">
                <sv:value>info.magnolia.cv.CVSkills</sv:value>
            </sv:property>
        </sv:node>
    </sv:node>
</sv:code>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a JOIN clause but use an OR in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT parent.* 
FROM [nt:base] AS parent 
INNER JOIN [nt:base] AS child ON ISCHILDNODE(child,parent)
WHERE parent.ocm_classname = 'info.magnolia.cv.CurriculumVitae' 
  AND ( CONTAINS(parent.*, 'java') OR CONTAINS(child.*,'java') )
```

This creates two selectors, `parent` and `child`, and uses an `ISCHILDNODE` join criteria to ensure that nodes in the `child` selector are children of the nodes in the `parent` selector. Then, it uses an OR criteria to include in the results parent nodes that contain 'java' or child nodes that contain 'java'.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. While the query does not work in this state it helped me solve the problem. 
You can see that the `info.magnolia.cv.CVSkills` is not a direct node of  `info.magnolia.cv.CurriculumVitae`, but I added a new join for the middle node and it worked. Also, it returns duplicate rows but as far as I know there is no `distinct` in SQL2

Comment: Also, `join` doesn't work, it gives an error, I needed to use `inner join`

Comment: You are correct that the JSR-283 specification does not define `DISTINCT`. I also updated my suggested query to use `INNER JOIN`. Some implementations of JCR2 (e.g., ModeShape) do support non-standard extensions to JCR-SQL2, including `DISTINCT` and `JOIN` (where the join type defaults to `INNER` like SQL-99).